# Download file in Grails web app and display some content as well

Tags: grails, download

Okay, so this is how I am downloading a file in my web app now.

```
try {        
    response.setContentType('application/octet-stream')
    response.setHeader('Content-Disposition', "Attachment; Filename=\"downloadFile\"")
    for (fooName in fooNames) {
        response.outputStream << getSomeBinaryDataFor(fooName).getBytes()
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    redirect controller: 'some', action: 'where'
} finally {
    response.outputStream.close()
}

return someParamMap
```

And I am unable to see the the content from `someParamMap`. Now, I understand that it's probably because I am closing the response output stream. But is there a way I can display the content I have in `someParamMap`?

Comment: How about, Create a byte array from values in your map and then response.outputStream << bytes

Comment: use ajax, send to server file, and after it show result. It's the simplest way, i think

Answer (score 1):

No.  You'll need to do this in two requests and two controller actions.  One request to get the file and one to render the meta data.

Comment: Can you give some details about it?

Comment: Sure.  You'll want to make a view and render it the normal way with Grails. This will allow you to pass meta data from the controller action and display it in the view.  The file download part would make a 2nd request to the server and use a different controller action.